# Clear Filter Functionality Not Working Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm working on a filtering feature in a Vue application. I'm new to Vue, and I have the filter semi-working. It successfully allows me to select an asset type from the dropdown, and will filter the results accordingly. But what's not working is the `clearFilters` method.

My goal is to reset the `assetType` to an empty string and the `filterResults` array to empty, and my thought was that since checking the length of `filterResults`, when I clear it it would return to displaying the entire un-filtered array.

What am I doing wrong? Any information would be greatly appreciated.

```js
<template>
  <div ref="content">
    <div class="container pt-3 text-center">
      <div class="filter-container">
        <div class="btn-group">
          <button
            v-ripple="'rgba(255, 255, 255, .2)'"
            @click="showAssetType = !showAssetType"
            class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle"
            data-toggle="dropdown"
            aria-haspopup="true"
            aria-expanded="false"
            style="max-height: 40px;">
            {{assetType ? assetType : 'Asset Type'}}
          </button>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" :style="'display:' + (showAssetType ? 'block' : 'none') + ';'">
            <a class="dropdown-item" @click.prevent="setAssetFilter('all')" href="#!">All Assets</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" @click.prevent="setAssetFilter('USD'); filterByAssetType()" href="#!">USD</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" @click.prevent="setAssetFilter('GBP'); filterByAssetType()" href="#!">GBP</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" @click.prevent="setAssetFilter('CAD'); filterByAssetType()" href="#!">CAD</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  <div id="data-table" v-if="filterResults.length > 0">
    <div v-for="(transaction, index) in filterResults" :key="index">
      <global-history-item>
        <template v-slot:header>
          <h1 class="date">{{formatDate(transaction.date)}}</h1>
            <div class="transaction-header-wrapper">
              <p class="transaction-text">{{formatString(transaction.tx_type)}} Transaction</p>
              <p class="transaction-text" style="text-align: right">{{transaction.coin_type}}</p>
            </div>
        </template>
        <template v-slot:content>
          <global-transaction :transaction='transaction' @updateClassType="updateClassType" />
        </template>
      </global-history-item>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="data-table">
    <div v-for="(item, index) in totalHistory" :key="index">
      <div v-if="item.tx_type">
        <global-history-item>
          <template v-slot:header>
            <h1 class="date">{{formatDate(item.date)}}</h1>
              <div class="transaction-header-wrapper">
                <p class="transaction-text">{{formatString(item.tx_type)}} Transaction</p>
              </div>
          </template>
          <template v-slot:content>
            <global-transaction :transaction='item' @updateClassType="updateClassType" />
          </template>
        </global-history-item>
      </div>
      <div v-else-if="item.invoice_id">
        <global-history-item>
          <template v-slot:header>
            <h1 class="date">{{formatDate(item.date)}}</h1>
            <div class="invoice-header-wrapper">
              <p class="invoice-text">Invoice Created</p>
              <p class="invoice-text">Invoice #{{item.invoice_id}}</p>
            </div>
          </template>
          <template v-slot:content>
            <global-invoice :invoice='item' />
          </template>
        </global-history-item>
      </div>
      <div v-else>
        <global-history-item>
          <template v-slot:header>
            <h1 class="date">{{formatDate(item.date)}}</h1>
            <div class="invoice-header-wrapper">
              <p class="invoice-text">Login Event</p>
              <br />
            </div>
          </template>
          <template v-slot:content>
            <global-account-activity :message='"A successful login to your account was made"' />
          </template>
        </global-history-item>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
... imports removed for brevity

export default {
  name: 'Global',
  components: { },
  props: ['totalHistory', 'printFormat'],
  mixins: ['formatDate', 'formatMenuLabel'],
  data () {
    return {
      showAssetType: false,
      showClassType: false,
      activityType: '',
      assetType: '',
      filterResults: [],
      printMode: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setAssetFilter (value) {
      this.showAssetType = false
      this.assetType = value
    },
    formatString (str) {
      const firstLetter = str.charAt(0)
      const remainder = str.slice(1)
      return firstLetter.toUpperCase() + remainder
    },
    updateClassType (transactionRecord) {
      this.$store.dispatch('updateTransactionType', transactionRecord)
    },
    updateTransaction (transactionRecord) {
      console.log('in updateTransaction', transactionRecord)
      this.$store.dispatch('updateTransactionNote', transactionRecord)
    },
    filterByAssetType () {
      const selectedCurrency = this.assetType
      if (this.assetType === 'all') {
        this.clearFilters()
      } else {
        this.filterResults = this.totalHistory.filter(function (trans) {
          return trans.currency === selectedCurrency
        })
      }
    },
    clearFilters () {
      return (this.assetType = '') && (this.filterResults = [])
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I am not mistaking, you only want the method `clearFilters`, to work? If so, try:

```
    clearFilters () {
      this.assetType = ''
      this.filterResults = []
    }
```

The logical AND operator (&&) is not to chain expressions. It’s to do an expression if the first expression is truthy.

First expression && second expression, example

```
  const questionAnswered = true
  console.log(questionAnswered && "Hooray!")
  // will log "Hooray!" (Expression 2)
```

If you set `questionAnswered` to false, it will log false (expression 1)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Jens rewrite of clearFilters().  The original looked odd to me.

I had started creating a sample component to demonstrate possibly simplifying the filtering process when there were no answers.  Since I have finished it and it works, I am posting it.

ClearFilters.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="clear-filters">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>NAME</th>
              <th>CURRENCY</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr v-for="asset in filteredAssets" :key="asset.id">
              <td>{{ asset.name }}</td>
              <td>{{ asset.currency }}</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="criteria-label">FILTER CRITERIA:</label>
          <select class="form-control" v-model="currentCriteria">
            <option v-for="(criteria, index) in criteriaOptions" :key="index" :value="criteria">{{ criteria }}</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" @click="resetFilter">Reset</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import assets from './clear-filters-data.js';

  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        assets: assets,
        criteriaOptions: [
          'ALL', 'USD', 'GBP', 'CAD'
        ],
        currentCriteria: 'ALL'
      }
    },
    computed: {
      filteredAssets() {
        if (this.currentCriteria === 'ALL') {
          return this.assets;
        }
        else {
          return this.assets.filter( asset => asset.currency === this.currentCriteria);
        }
      }
    },
    methods: {
      resetFilter() {
        this.currentCriteria = 'ALL';
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<style scoped>
  .criteria-label {
    font-weight: bold;
  }
</style>
```

Test data:

```
const assets = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'asset1',
    currency: 'USD'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'asset2',
    currency: 'USD'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'asset3',
    currency: 'USD'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'asset4',
    currency: 'GBP'
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: 'asset5',
    currency: 'GBP'
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    name: 'asset6',
    currency: 'GBP'
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    name: 'asset7',
    currency: 'CAD'
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    name: 'asset8',
    currency: 'CAD'
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    name: 'asset9',
    currency: 'CAD'
  },
]

export default assets;
```